# Google Cloud Scheduler - Automating all projects

Tags: google-cloud-platform

In an effort to reduce cost on GCP, I want to shutdown the VM's that are currently running, when people leave the office. This is easy todo within a single project, but my question is then, is it possible to scale this to all the projects I have available?

For instance, I can define these functions to start and stop VM's within a project and using the cloud scheduler i can achieve what I want. But within my organization there are alot of projects, that gets created and deleted all the time, so it seems like a waste to this individually.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Yes, you can do this. Assign a service account to the service (Cloud Functions?) that is shutting down instances to have privileges to each project. Create a list of each project. If these projects are under the same organization, you can scan the org for all projects.

Comment: Yes, you also can grant the service account role to the Organisation Level, or Folder level. Like this, your function can view (list the VM) and shutdown all in all your project. Be careful, if you have production projects, play with tag for excluding some project when you search the VM to exclude.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this simple with Cloud Scheduler.

You can do this using target **HTTP Method** in your Cloud Scheduler, you can add **Auth Header** (Add OAuth token) with a particular or spesific service account that have full access to do it.

Then you can use Compute Engine API to do it.

Example :

Replace wrapped text below with your compute engine value parameter

- To stop Compute Engine :

> Target : HTTP
> HTTP Method : POST
> URL : https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/**your-project-name**/zones/**your-instance-zone**/instances/**your-instance-name**/stop

- To start Compute Engine :

> Target : HTTP
> HTTP Method : POST
> URL : https://compute.googleapis.com/compute/v1/projects/**your-project-name**/zones/**your-instance-zone**/instances/**your-instance-name**/start

You can read full example here https://www.nuslab.com/2020/07/start-shutdown-compute-engine-with-cloud-scheduler-gcp.html